# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'id _Nullable' from a function with result type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to have an object which keeps indexes of an array where id is the unique key and it's value is index (`{[id]:[index]}`)

I want to dynamically return that index i.e In javascript I would do something like this

```
const a = [{
  id: '451', 
  name: 'varun'
}]


const b = {
    '451': 0 
}

const c = '451' 

if (b[c]) return b[c] 
else return -1
```

What would be it's equivalent in obj c?

Currently I am doing this

```
@implementation Participants {
    NSMutableDictionary *participantsKey;
}. // Equivalent to const b above


- (NSInteger)doesParticipantExist:(NSString*)id {
    if ([participantsKey valueForKey: id]) {
      return [participantsKey valueForKey: id];
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

but this is throwing following warning

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'id _Nullable' from a function with result type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKey` returns a nullable object `'id _Nullable'`  NOT an `NSInteger` which is a `long` value.

```
[participantsKey valueForKey: id]
```

Your function's return type is `NSInteger` and that's why it's saying it can't convert a nullable object `'id _Nullable'` into `NSInteger`.

Here's what you can do to fix the issue.

```
- (NSInteger)doesParticipantExist:(NSString*)id {
    if ([participantsKey valueForKey:id]) {
        // Fix here
        return [(NSNumber*)[participantsKey valueForKey:id] integerValue];
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question as well as helping me out with my previous questions :)